# How can i get information by scanning barcode?

Tags: android, api

I would like to get product information by scanning the barcode. is that possible

if the information is in json it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you exactly looking for, you need to give more information, but you have a bunch of apps in the Play Store like ["Barcode Scanner"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=es)

Comment: I m looking for something that can return me a json or xml file having the product details when do the barcode scan

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library to integrate into your project, then you have a few options. Two of the most popular ones are next:

1. ML Kit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android
2. ZXing: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Logically besides the libraries you still need to code a way to pass images to the libraries. So, to code a camera, use the device system camera, or an image picker.

Comment: i want the information that deparmental store gets when they scan the barcode

Comment: These libraries will give you the information that holds the barcodes. You can test them, for example in the Google Play Store you can find the official ZXing app which uses the ZXing library I put in the answer. See if it gives you when scanning the information you need, and if it does then you know you can use such library: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en